# JS promise is getting called without calling it

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I don't know why is `promise1` keeps getting called even though I never tried to resolve it.

```
                    function successCallback() {
                        console.log("doSomething func succeeded with sucess");
                    }
                    
                    function failureCallback() {
                        console.log("doSomething func failed with error");
                    }

                    let promis1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log(`Finally got called`);
                        return res(successCallback());
                    }, 5000);
                    });
    
                    function promise2(value) {
                    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                        console.log(`This is getting called for some reason ${value}`)
                        return res(failureCallback());
                    });
                    }

                    Promise.resolve("6").then(promise2(6));
```

And here is the output that Im getting:

> This is getting called for some reason 6
>
> doSomething func failed with error
>
> Finally got called
>
> doSomething func succeeded with sucess
>
> [Done] exited with code=0 in 5.525 seconds

Comment: because [promises](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261) are [eager](https://medium.com/@_ericelliott/because-promises-are-eager-not-lazy-calling-axios-get-289c6e325f59) [maybe](https://medium.com/@dtipson/the-problem-with-promises-is-indeed-that-theyre-eagerly-evaluated-and-stateful-so-another-e3fef68989f4)?

Comment: `let promis1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {` ... see that function? (starts with `(res, rej) =>` it gets called as part of the Promise constructor

Comment: What is this meant to accomplish? You're executing the callbacks  instead of using them as parameters so they'll always execute (`failureCallback()` vs `failureCallback`). What is `Promise.resolve` doing in there.

Comment: @Jorg i'm just tinkering around to fully understand promises. I was having difficulty learning promises so digesting it piece by piece and introducing weird and complex ways was a way to help me understand how promises works

Comment: In that case, start by doing `rej(failureCallback)` and `res(successCallback)`.

Comment: @JaromandaX, wait, so node calls constructors of promises that are not even called ? damn, never knew that, thanks

Comment: no, it does not - you misunderstand the flow - oh, wait, what do you mean by promises that aren't called - do you mean promises with no `then` or `catch` attached? then, yes, a promise needs no `catch` or `then` attached to be constructed - as the construction callback code is called synchronously

Answer (score 2):

The function passed to `new Promise` is called immediately and synchronously by the promise constructor (unlike setTimeout) and is on the same stack as `new Promise`.

If the function passed to it throws then it results in a rejected promise:

```js
console.log(1);
const p = new Promise(
  (res,rej)=>{
    console.log(2);
    res();
  }
);
p.then(
  ()=>console.log(7)
);
console.log(3);

console.log(4);
const p2 = new Promise(
  (res,rej)=>{
    console.log(5);
    throw("an error");
  }
);
p2.catch(
  ()=>console.log(8)
);
console.log(6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will show you the flow of your code

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log(9)); // 9 will log once all the "synchronous" code below is completed
console.log(1);
let promis1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  console.log(2);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(10);
    return res('resolved 1');
  }, 5000);
});
console.log(3);
function promise2(value) {
  console.log(5);
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    console.log(6);
    return res('resolved 2');
  });
}
console.log(4);
promise2().then(() => {
  console.log(8);
});
console.log(7);
```

note: some (most?) promise implementations (including bluebird) will output 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8,10 - because `.then` callback is added to the end of the message queue - whereas, it may be the case that in `native` promises, the `.then` callback jumps the queue! (or maybe there's more to javascript engines these days than [this simple model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: thank you, could you explain why did promis1 get called? Maybe coz I came from C and the C way of triggering a function is only if it is found in main() is making me misinterpret node

Comment: because the constructor function you supply in the argument to `new Promise` is called, synchronously, as part of the new Promise construction - the similar answer by @HMR explains it - I would've thought the sequence of console.log's would've made the program flow quite obvious

Answer (score -2):

If this is part of a larger program. Change `let promis1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {` to let `promise1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {`

Hint : Spelling of the word "promise"

Comment: how does the name of the variable change the action of the new Promise constructor? hint: it doesn't. hint 2: probably a typo in the code posted here, rather than in the actual code itself (where promise1 would be undefined)