# Does Promise resolution start the moment the promise is created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

In the following code, I noticed that the promise was starting to get resolved the moment getProm() was called(I could notice the delay of 5 seconds on running the code).

I want to confirm whether promise is resolved immediately on creation or only in the following 2 cases. 1) Promise is resolved only when we do Promise.resolve explicitly 2) we make use of .then keyword

```
function getProm(){
    var prom1 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            resolve("Promise is resolved")
        },5000)
    })
    return prom1
}
var mypromise = getProm()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce what you say *In the following code, I noticed that the promise was getting resolved the moment getProm() was called*. The promise was only resolved after I called `.then` (or alternatives)

Comment: Your statement doesn't make sense. How you could notice something happening "the moment getProm was called" when you also "could notice the delay of 5 seconds". If it is delayed by 5 seconds then it isn't the moment that it is called!

Comment: Promise gets resolved when you call either `resolve` or `reject`. `.then()` has no impact on Promise fullfilment.

Comment: If your question is "does the code in a Promise function run no matter what?", then the answer to that is "yes". Just replace `resolve()` with `console.log()` and see for yourself.

Comment: @Adelin - really? I think the promise is resolved after 5000ms - regardless of anything else

Comment: @Quentin - what I meant by my statement was that I could notice the 5 second delay on running the above code. But, getProm() is only creating the promise and not resolving it. Then why am I able to see the 5 second delay?

Comment: that's a bit confusing to say "getProm()" doesn't resolve it ... after all, it is code inside that function (run later) that resolves it

Comment: @ChrisG - That exactly was my question. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three moments to distinguish:

- The moment the callback is called that you pass to `new Promise`: the so-called promise constructor callback. This is immediate: it will execute before any other code that follows the `new Promise` expression. In your case, it means `setTimeout` is executed immediately.
- The moment the promise resolves. This happens when the `resolve` or `reject` functions are called that are provided to the promise constructor callback. In your case this happens after a delay of 5 seconds.
- Detection of a resolved promise. This always happens asynchronously: with ES6 promises you cannot detect that a promise has resolved synchronously, even if the code calls `resolve` without delay. You detect resolution with a `then` callback (or `await`). This callback is not called before the current call stack has ran to completion and is emptied. Whether you detect such resolution or not, this does not delay the actual resolution of the promise. If you would execute a `then` after a 10 minute delay, it would trigger the `then` callback in the next microtask, even though the promise had already been resolved long ago. You can have several `then` calls on the same promise: they will all trigger their callbacks.

Comment: This `microtask` you speak of ... would that explain why in [this answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48919141/5053002) earlier today, the different order of console.log statements between Bluebird and native promises? Bluebird (and other promise implementations including my own) behave as I actually expected (the last .then is executed after the first settimeout is "placed" on the (message?) queue ... because this queue is executed in the order that "tasks" are placed on it. Where as native promises .then seems to jump this queue (.then is placed at head of queue?)

Comment: Yes, the microtask queue is a separate queue, which is processed as part of the current task. Only when the microtask queue is empty, will the task complete, followed by the usual message queue processing (where also `setTimeout` events are put). DOM Mutation events seem to also get some priority (browser dependent), so a custom promise implementation (tied to DOM) could try to use that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - had me confused all day :p